# How to model categorical variables with non-numerical values using logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I have demographic data, data related to their branch, department and performance rating. I am using logistic regression to build a model which can predict people which are likely to perform above a certain threshold say 70% of rating.How do I include variables such as designation, department and make sense out of it.

I have put the variables as it is in the model as some of them have a p-value of less than 0.05.For ex. among the department, one of the department is significant. How do i interpret this result?

Work experience, performance rating, zones (regions), some departments are coming out to be significant but qualification isn't. i expected it to come as significant. I am not sure if i am treating the variables right or how to interpret the results.

Comment: You can use one-hot encoding for categorical values or numeric encoding. For one-hot encode, you would need to restrict to a smaller number of levels

Comment: Can you please explain with example. Let us say, we have 5 departments: a,b,c,d,e and f. Can you please elaborate now how i can do what you are telling?

Comment: The department field will become 5 fields say dep_a, dep_b, ... and each field have 1 and 0 for the matching department. Please read about `one-hot encoding`. That will help

Comment: Hi Sonny, Thank you for helping me out here. The problem with one-hot encoding is that if one of the categorical variables has 8 values then i will have to make 7 variables and if i have 4 such variables then it will amount to 28 such variables which i believe affects the quality and robustness of the model.